# Linear regression from function

Tags: functional-analysis, regression

I have a function given by its analytical form $f(x,y,z)=0$. Is is possible to calculate linear regression directly from this function on a selected neighborhood of a point? I want to "approximate" this neighorhood by a plane.

I can sample this by taking several points from this neighborhood, but its quite slow if I increase number of points $N$ (like $N > 1000$).